# React redirect after login

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router

I have a ajax login in React app. It handles LoginForm component. Aplication also uses [React router](https://reactrouter.com/)
After ajax login I would like to make something like redirect to another React page. I dont know how to properly redirect from login page to homepage after successful login. Can somebody help me please? I am using class style to making components.

This is the code from LoginForm component:

```
    sendData(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({'errors': [], 'success': []});

        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.set('name', this.state.name);
        formData.set('password', this.state.password);

        axios({
            method: 'POST',
            //url: 'http://localhost:8000/login'
            data: formData,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            }
        })
            .then(response => {
               // Here should be the redirect to another React page
            })
            .catch(response => {
                this.setState({errors: ['Login fails. Try it again later please.']})
            });
    }
```

React Router looks like

```
<div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li className="nav-item">
            <NavLink to="/" className="nav-link">Home</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
            <NavLink to="/login" className="nav-link">Login</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
            <NavLink to="/about" className="nav-link">About</NavLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div className="container-fluid">
    <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact>
                <Home />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/login">
                <Login />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
        </Switch>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using functional components, you can use use `useHistory` hook provided by `react-router-dom`.

On a successful login, redirect to home page as shown below:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const Login = () => {
   const routerHistory = useHistory();
   ...

   const sendData = (e) => {
      ...
      .then(response => {
         // Here should be the redirect to another React page
         routerHistory.push('/');
      }) 
      ...
   }
   
   ...
}
```

You could also use `history` prop which is one of the prop passed from React Router. This will work in class based components too.

```
class Login {
     ...

     sendData(e) {
        ...
        .then(response => {
           // Here should be the redirect to another React page
           this.props.history.push('/');
        })
        ...
     } 

    ...
}
```

If `Login` component is not passed router props because of the hierarchy of the components in your app, then you can use `withRouter` higher order component to get access to `history` object.

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class Login {
   ...
}

export default withRouter(Login);
```

For details see:

- [useHistory](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory)
- [history](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history)
- [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter)

Comment: I am using class components. Can you show the solution for classes?

Comment: I am getting error History is undefined. In LoginForm I make 
`import { History } from "react-router-dom"` but I am not sure ho to get History to component. I am sorry I am starting with React.